# Finite Sum of Power of Cosine Function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Suppose I have the following sum:  Let $n=qr$

$$S_n=\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{qj}\cos^n{\left(\frac{j\pi}{r}\right)}$$

I am interested in which values of $r>1$ produce an integer $k$ for all $n>0$.  I'm not even sure how to approach this problem, save to say that at least for certain values of $j$ and $r$, cosine can equal $\pm 1$ or 0.  But how can this be shown to be an integer for $r>1$ if at all?  Should I use the Euler formula $e^{in\theta}=\cos{n\theta}+I\sin{n\theta}$ and distinguish real and imaginary parts in order to help?

Comment: $\cos(n\dots)$ or $\cos^n(\dots)$ or $\cos(\dots)^n$?

Comment: the problem is $\cos^n(...)$